# Mysql Failed to started after mysql dump restore process

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

i tried to restore a db backup to a newly created database, suddenly its starts showing error. Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`
so i checked `/var/log/syslog` which shows error like :

```
kernel: [50646755.461546] init: mysql main process (31830) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50646755.461590] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
kernel: [50646756.363273] init: mysql post-start process (31831) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50646756.380883] type=1400 audit(1404213477.915:91): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=31854 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

then i tried

```
cd /etc/apparmor.d/
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

to disable mysqld from apparmor.

```
cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles

/usr/sbin/tcpdump (enforce)
/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script (enforce)
/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action (enforce)
/sbin/dhclient (enforce)
```

mysql removed from apparmor

then I again tried to start mysql which shows error.
`tailf /var/log/syslog`

```
kernel: [50647375.532797] init: mysql main process (32120) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50647375.532843] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
kernel: [50647376.405541] init: mysql post-start process (32121) terminated with status 1
init: mysql main process (32148) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50647376.611944] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
kernel: [50647377.490963] init: mysql post-start process (32149) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50647377.671609] init: mysql main process (32176) terminated with status 1
kernel: [50647377.671654] init: mysql respawning too fast, stopped
```

please help me, I need use same exciting database. I don't want lose it.

Comment: Please check the actual mysql error log.  Often this is found  in the directory /var/log/mysql.